# Referring manually created collection stored in mongo atlas from node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

i am currently creating a nodejs app that deals with huge data. I created a table(.csv file) in excel and then converted it to to **JSON** file and added the document to MongoDB Atlas under the collection
**players**. The collection is huge, hence i did not create the collection inside from Node.JS. Now I want to refer to the fields inside the MongoDB collection from my Node.JS application and using it as a model..
how to solve this problem.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create a mongoose schema and model as you do normally. But, name the model `player` so that it points to your mongodb's `players` collection.